# currently trying to create a new SSH passphrase

Tags: windows, git-bash, new-operator

Hey im a brand new coder doing prework for a bootcamp. currentl creating my first passphrase and need to figure out what file to put it in that isnt a directory. should i create a new file or use an existing?

i tried  "/c/Users/garyl/ ssh stuff" "/c/Users/garyl/.ssh/id_rsa:" and was told they dont exist then tried the directory /c/Users/garyl/:

Comment: The private key goes into your home directory: `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, replace the tilde by /c/Users/garyl/ in your case.
You have to configure the server with your public key, in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Note that this file and folder need specific rights, 700 for `.ssh` and 600 for `authorized_keys`.